# Why is connection keep-alive only sent on first request with WebRequest?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, webrequest, keep-alive

I have the following code for testing purposes

```
for( int i = 0; i < 5 ; i++ ) {   
   var url = "http://myserver.com/Warmup";
   var request = WebRequest.Create(url);
   using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse()) {
       using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream()) {
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream)) {
               reader.ReadToEnd();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

When I run it with Fiddler I see that only the first request has `Connection: Keep-Alive` header.

This means that if the server is IIS programmed to shutdown the application pool after some time of inactivity and that pool shutdown happens after the first request but before the next one then the next request that comes from the client will not have `Connection: Keep-Alive` set and so keep-alive will not kick in.

Why is `Connection: Keep-Alive` only sent for the first request and not for the later requests?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP/1.1 uses keep-alive connections by default. A client or server must explicitly indicate that they don't want Keep-Alive behavior by sending a `Connection: close` header.

The `Connection: Keep-Alive` header is sent on the first request only because the client doesn't yet know whether the server supports `HTTP/1.1` or if it will return a `HTTP/1.0` response. After the server confirms that it supports `HTTP/1.1` by sending a response using that version, the client knows that it can safely drop the redundant header.

Answer (score -1):

I think it is because you are using a TCP connection for the request. Just as mentioned [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_persistent_connection) the server creates one TCP connection which is in charge of all the requests you are performing.

Since TCP uses a three way handshake the server and client always know if the connection is still available or not. So everytime the server closes a connection it will send a so called FIN bit to the client so that the client knows that the connection is not established anymore.

Although you create the webrequest 5 times, the client already knows the request because it is available in its TCP/IP pool and can reuse the connection, unless the client demands to end the connection finally.

You can find more information in [this wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) about this topic.

Comment: Isn't the TCP connection broken when the application pool is shut down?

Comment: You are only closing the WebResponse but not the WebRequest. I think the entry in the TCP/IP pool will be create by WebRequest.Create(url) and then be stored. And I think everytime you create a new WebRequest to the same URL, the application will have a look in that pool if there is already a open TCP/IP connection to that specific URL. Correct me if I am wrong... I did not dive deep into that topic :-)

Comment: Again, the server side has the application pool restarted - the process that accepted the first request just ends and starts a new, so I expect the TCP connection to not survive.

Comment: When and how exactly do you restart the application pool? The TCP connection has to been shutdown by a three-way handshake aswell, so that the client knows that he cannot send anymore data. In a TCP connection you have no "server" or "client", both endpoints are equal, so maybe one of them did not finish the connection properly?

Comment: The server side asks the application pool to recycle after the first request is processed.